# How can we be sure that a Pallet-account/address is unique in a chain and no one else in the chain can replicate the same address?

Tags: pallet, subkey, palletid

In Ethereum, the contract address/account isn't formed trivially from a cryptographically-generated private-public key pair, but rather by using a separate method, as described [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/accounts/#:%7E:text=The%20contract%20address%20is%20usually,(the%20%E2%80%9Cnonce%E2%80%9D).).

In Substrate, similar to this, a pallet-account is formed from inside the runtime by passing a PalletId (a unique identifier assigned to the pallet) to the [into_account()](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/sp_runtime/traits/trait.AccountIdConversion.html#method.into_account) function instead of passing a random seed as is done for normal account formation.
For example: `T::PalletId::get().into_account()`

My question now is, how can we be sure that the account address won't be replicated by anyone else/ other pallets in the chain?

Comment: are you trying to convert a PalletId into an AccountId type?

Comment: You mean one could generate accounts until you get the `AccountId` of a Pallet and then steal the Pallets' funds?

Comment: @Purple_Turtle Yes, that's the intent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot be sure that it won't be replicated. A different pallet could use the same seed (pallet id) to generate an account id and thus "impersonate" your pallet. This is not a problem, though, because the assumptions about pallets are different from smart contracts: Pallets are trusted modules included in the runtime deliberately by the people building the runtime (in contrast to smart contracts that can be created in a permissionless way). Thus it is fine to assume that the pallets included in a runtime cooperate with each other.
If you need to generate an account id that cannot be easily replicated, you will want to use hashing on unpredictable/uncontrollable inputs such as the account sending an extrinsic in combination with its nonce and the current block number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: @AsmitaDhungana Could you mark this this reply as the answer?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier Sure!